# Get user name from user_id in pivot table with eager load laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, left-join

I have 2 models and one pivot table:

```
users
id

experiments
id

experiments_assigns
id
exp_id
user_id
```

The pivot table experiments_assigns has extra fields but I have not created a specific model for it.
So I want to eager load all experiments with their assignments (if any) and the associated user details.
I can get it work except for getting user details..
In controller I have this code:

```
$experiments = Experiments::with('assigns')->get();
```

But no way I can figure out how to load the associated user details by user_id returned in pivot property.

This is Experminemts class:

```
class Experminemts extends Model {
   
    public function assigns() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Experminemts::class,
            'experminemts_assigns',
            'exp_id'
        )->withPivot('name', 'description', 'date_start',   'date_end', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

experiments_assigns table migration:

```
Schema::create('experiments_assigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('description')->nullable(true); 
    $table->dateTime('date_start');
    $table->dateTime('date_end');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('exp_id');//->unsigned()
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('exp_id')->references('id')->on('experiments')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

So what I get for assigns is:

> { "exp_id": 6, "name": "Experiment assignation 1", "description": null, "date_start": "2022-11-29 14:17:00", "date_end": "2022-12-30 14:17:00", "user_id": 9 }

Where I would expect:

> { "exp_id": 6, "name": "Experiment assignation 1", "description": null, "date_start": "2022-11-29 14:17:00", "date_end": "2022-12-30 14:17:00", "user_id": 9, "user_name": "Some Name", "user_email": "some@ema.il" }

Thanks

Comment: your relationship is saying that Experiments belongs to many Experiments ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create eloquent model for your pivot table ExperimentAssign and in it define relationship for user:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

maybe you will need to define the table too:

```
protected $table = 'experiments_assigns';
```

in your Experiment model add relationship:

```
public function experiment_assigns()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ExperimentAssign::class);
}
```

and then call:

```
$experiments = Experiments::with('experiment_assigns.user')->get();
```

Comment: That's right. It's a working solution I have already implemented. But is there a way to do the same without creating ExperimentAssign model?

Comment: in you experiments model you can have many users:
`
public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            User::class,
            'experminemts_assigns',
            'user_id'
        )->withPivot('name', 'description', 'date_start',   'date_end', 'user_id');
    }
`
and call `$experiments = Experiments::with('users')->get();`